# Substitute result into italics for legend labels

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a legend for a plot, showing the group name, then the size in italics. I've tried both `substitute` and `bquote` to do this, without success:

```
# Some sample data
groupNames <- letters[1:5]
groupSizes <- seq(10, 50, length=5)

# Using bquote
legend.labels <-sapply(
  sapply(1:length(groupNames), function(i) {
    bquote(.(groupNames[i])~"("~italic(.(groupSizes[i]))~")")
  }), as.expression)
plot(1:5, colors=1:5)
legend("topleft", fill=1:5, legend=legend.labels)

# using substitute
legend.labels <-sapply(
  sapply(1:length(groupNames), function(i) {
    substitute(a~"("~italic(b)~")", list(a=groupNames[i], b=groupSizes[i]))
  }), as.expression)
plot(1:5, colors=1:5)
legend("topleft", fill=1:5, legend=legend.labels)
```

How do I italicise an evaluated variable within a plot label?

Comment: The `plotmath` environment doesn't support italic numbers. Add `text(3,2, expression(italic(30*x)))`. See how just the `x` looks italic. From the `?plotmath` help page: "Note that bold, italic and bolditalic [...] do not apply to numeric constants." You can get italic numbers by changing the font face: `legend("topleft", fill=1:5, legend= groupSizes, text.font=3)` but that doesn't work with expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting an example in the `?legend` help page, perhaps you could do something like

```
plot(1:5, col=1:5)
temp <- legend("topleft", legend = groupNames,
               text.width = max(strwidth(paste(groupNames, groupSizes, " ()"))),
               fill=1:5, xjust = 0, yjust = 1)
text(temp$text$x +strwidth(groupNames) + strwidth(" "), temp$text$y,
    paste0("(", groupSizes, ")"), font=3, adj=c(0,.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Damn, that's painful (especially when using `ncols`) I think I may just stick to non-italics!

Comment: Actually, what's so painful when using `ncols=`? With this sample data it seems to work just fine.